# Python Multiple Exponents

Tags: python, math

Code:

```
a=2**3
print a
b=a**2
print b
c=b**1
print c
print 2**3**2**1
```

Results:

```
8
64
64
512
```

Why does Python evaluate the last line of code as 512?

Comment: What would you expect to see instead of 512? Have you tried putting parentheses around different parts to see if/how it changes the result?

Comment: correction to original question inline `a=2**3
print a
b=a**2
print b
c=b**1
print c
print 2**3**2**1`

Answer (score 3):

[Exponentiation groups from the right to the left.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

```
>>> 2**3**2**1
512
>>> 2**(3**(2**1))
512
```

Comment: You can perhaps also add the correct way of getting 64 here: `((2**3)**2)**1`